# Generate url aliasing based on taxonomy term

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-taxonomy

I have a vocab category and four terms within it. what i want to do is if content is tagged with a termin in particular say "term1" to have the url generated as word1/[node:title] and for all the other tags just the standard url formatting.

If i wanted the term in the url obviously id use pattern replacement but i want another word to be used if a particular tag is used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a simple way actually to anyone who need a similar solution use the module Entity Reference.

http://drupal.org/project/entityreference

I just created a new field for the user account select entity reference then you can choose any entity within drupal to reference.
(ie so you can select a term/content/anything)

Answer (score 5):

I can't think of an easy plug-and-play way of achieving this. You may have to create your own token for the "Default path pattern" in Pathauto's URL alias settings:

```
/**
 * Implementation of hook_token_info().
 */
function MODULE_token_info() {
  $info['tokens']['node']['node-term-path'] = array(
    'name'        => t('Node path by term'),
    'description' => t('The path to a node based on its taxonomy terms.'),
  );
  return $info;
}

/**
 * Implementation of hook_tokens().
 */
function MODULE_tokens($type, $tokens, array $data = array(), array $options = array()) {
  $replacements = array();
  if ($type == 'node' && !empty($data['node'])) {
    $node = $data['node'];

    foreach ($tokens as $name => $original) {
      switch ($name) {
        case 'node-term-path':
          $items = field_get_items('node', $node, 'TAXONOMY_FIELD_NAME');
          foreach ($items as $item) {
            $tids[] = $item['tid'];
          }
          if (in_array(TID_OF_TERM1, $tids)) {
            // Path for nodes with term1
            $replacements[$original] = 'word1/'. pathauto_cleanstring($node->title);
          }
          else {
            // Path for other nodes
            $replacements[$original] = 'content/'. pathauto_cleanstring($node->title);
          }
          break;
      }
    }
  }
  return $replacements;
}
```